# How can I set a Cancel Button in the first step of Visual Workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow, flow, ui

I want to have a cancel button, right beside the next button, in the first step of the visual workflow.

As far I have seen, it looks like is not possible.

Any idea, how can I do this?

Regards!

Endrit.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can we provide custom buttons in a flow, or provide the ability to cancel an interview?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79798/can-we-provide-custom-buttons-in-a-flow-or-provide-the-ability-to-cancel-an-int)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually I don't want to develop any code through a page controller or any JS remoting trick. I was thinking if there is any attribute like finishLocation, in the <flow:interview> tag, where you specify where to send the user after processes the flow. 
But, anyway, I think I'm going for a custom VF Page development. I don't see any other choice. 
Thanks again!

Comment: The only option you have is whether or not to pause a flow.