# Exiting a screen flow from a screen that contains required input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have a screen flow with two screens.

- Screen 1 contains a form with a required field ("Credit Score") and two buttons: Cancel and Next:

[image]

I would like to give the user the option to exit the screen flow on screen 1 by clicking the Cancel button (clicking Cancel should end the flow and close the modal). Surprisingly, [there doesn't seem to be any OOB support for this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdW9zUAF/allow-flow-designer-exit-flow-button) and I'm yet to learn Visualforce, so I resorted to looking for custom buttons on the App Exchange.

I went with the [**Flow Button Bar**](https://unofficialsf.com/flow-button-bar-new-and-improved/). The component allows you to associate a value to each button you add to the screen and returns the value of the button that was clicked. So, I added two buttons to Screen 1: 1) a Cancel button with value "Cancel" and 2) a Next button with value "Next":

[image]

In Button Bar Settings, I set Action Mode to "Navigation":

[image: ![enter image description here]

I tried to capture the value of the clicked button by manually assigning its value to a text variable called `bttn_group`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Finally, I added a Decision element that checks the value of `bttn_group` and routes to `End` if `bttn_group == Cancel`:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

The resulting flow looks like this:

[image]

**Problem**

Clicking Cancel doesn't work. Whatever event handler is on the button seems to be intercepted by the validation rule on the required input:

[image]

I'm not sure why this is, but it seems `bttn_group` might not capturing the value properly. I tested this by adding a visibility rule on the "Current liquidity" input that says to show the input only if `bttn_group == Cancel`:

[image]

But, as you can see in the gif above, when I click on the Cancel button in the debugger, the "Current liquidity" input doesn't appear. So, `bttn_group` is not being set to "Cancel" when I click the Cancel button. **Maybe I haven't assigned the value properly?**

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and don't know what to try next.

Comment: Here's a link to the [Flow Button Bar](https://unofficialsf.com/flow-button-bar-new-and-improved/) docs. Couldn't add it in my post because I need >10 rep points to post more than 8 links.

Comment: Here, have ten rep. This question is well-written. Welcome to the community, I hope you enjoy your stay here and come back often.

Comment: Yay! Thank you @sfdcfox :) Would you know of a declarative workaround for this issue by any chance? I came across [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/79801/123882) to a similar question you had asked and I don't mind doing it programmatically, but not sure where to start.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not a flow expert, but let me try to build one real quick.

Comment: Thank you, I tried toggling the validation rule according to the value of`bttn_group` (i.e. `{!bttn_bar.value} == "Cancel" || NOT(ISBLANK({!Credit_Score})`), but that doesn't work.

Comment: Has anyone found alternative solution or answer to fix this ? @user135792

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using validation,use the conditional visibility of the required field, `{!buttonselect.value} != cancel`  . This should hide the component before navigating onto the next action within your flow.

It's quite interesting how it works, I guess the flow button bar selects the values first upon click and then hides the input component based on conditional visibility, and then executes the flow navigate action to move to the next screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Simple, Use in Decision element, the operator 'Contains'. i.e bttn_group 'Contains' Cancel.